# Subtracting two different data type numbers

Tags: c#, math, textbox, type-conversion

I'm trying to get result of `textBox19` numeric (9,2) for example *17050.00* and substract from it value in `textBox20` where are numbers like *120*. So *17050.00 - 120*.

I tried to make this :

```
textBox21.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox19.Text) - 
Convert.ToDouble(textBox20.Text)).ToString();
```

It should do: It should subtract textBox19 - textBox20. and show result in textBox21.

It does:
But when I debug in `textBox19` is still *17050.00* and in `textBox20` is *120*.
I would like to show the result in `textBox21.Text`

This line of code is giving me this exception : `Input string was not in correct format.` When I change value in textBox19 from *17050.00* to* 17050* the program keeps continuing and dont fall.

May I ask where do I make a mistake?

Comment: That line of code won't change either the 19th or 20th textboxes, it will change the 21st.  Does *that* have the difference of the two values?  If you want the other two textboxes to change, what do you expect to be in them?

Comment: You aren't changing the text of `textBox19` and `textBox20`, so you shouldn't expect the text to change. You are changing the text of `textBox21`.

Comment: I'm confused. You are trying to store the subtraction of two values into a third textbox (`textBox21`). What are you expecting it to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: You should really,really,really use more meaningful names for your controls ;-)

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your time. I wanted to substract these two textboxes, but my lack of knowledge and 20 days programming c#  forced me to do that. :/ Would you please help me how to subtract these two numbers?

Comment: What is your expected output? And what is your program currently outputting?

Comment: @BlazeM You have been asked several clarifying questions.  If you want help you'll need to answer them.  If you don't, we can't help you.

Comment: @BlazeM: So what is the `Text` in `textBox21` now, "16930"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter There is no output, because the program stop working. When dubugging textBox20 - textBox19 is like (17050.00 - 120) I think this is the problém?

Comment: @Servy Sorry for not saying what is my desire output. My desire output is substract of these 2 textBoxes (textBox20-textBox19) and show result in textBox21. I have updated my question before so you can see my answer.

Comment: @BlazeM: "Stop working" is different that `17050.00 - 120`. So what does the program?

Comment: If your program is not working, are you sure the error is on this specific line?

Comment: @BlazeM If you're getting an error, exception, etc. then that's radically different than that's very relevant to your problem, and your question should state that you're getting an exception, what it is, where it's occurring, any any other relevant information about it.  In your case my guess is that it's failing to parse the text that you have, but without further info that's all we can do, guess.

Comment: @sora0419 it says : Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for your time trying to solve my problém. I have updated my question again. Sorry for my curt info.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hello, the textBox21 doesnt show up any result because the program falls with an exception: Input string was not in correct format. But when I debug and change value 17050.00 to 17050 I get result 16930

Comment: @BlazeM Well there you go, your input string wasn't in the correct format.  Format your strings correctly, or use a parsing method that supports the format you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tobsey provided pretty much the approach I'd take, but there's some vagueness in your question, so I'm going to throw in my 2 cents.

I don't know what you're doing to set the value of textBox21, e.g. clicking a button or such, but I'm just going to swing in with the TextChanged event.

In my *FormName*.Designer.cs, I have the following lines in InitializeComponent():

```
this.TextBox19.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ChangeValue);
this.TextBox20.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ChangeValue);
```

In the actual *FormName*.cs file, I have the following:

```
private void ChangeValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double text20, text19;
    if (
        !double.TryParse(TextBox19.Text, out text19) ||
        !double.TryParse(TextBox20.Text, out text20)
    )
    {
        TextBox21.Text = "Can't calculate.";
        return;
    }

    TextBox21.Text = ( text19 - text20 ).ToString();
}
```

As to why you were getting the [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `Input string was not in correct format.`, I couldn't tell you.  Maybe there's a localization issue, in which case, you're going to have to modify the `TryParse` above to use the proper [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) format as well as the ToString().  Look up "Formatting Types" on MSDN as I can only post 2 links.  That's the first thing to come to mind as I tried 17050.00 and 17050 in my tests, and didn't have any issues.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer, I tried your code but when debug I still have 17050.00. but when I change textBox19 to 17050 it calculates great. I fill this textbox with from SQL might this be the problém?

Comment: How are you setting the value?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly those two values do not look like they should be stored in `double`. They look like monetary values which should be stored as decimals.

Rewrite your code to something like the following:

```
decimal textBox19Value; //Needs a better name
decimal textBox20Value; //Needs a better name

if (!decimal.TryParse(textBox19.Text, out textBox19Value))
{
    // textBox19 doesn't contain a valid decimal
    // present error to user and return
}

if (!decimal.TryParse(textBox20.Text, out textBox20Value))
{
    // textBox20 doesn't contain a valid decimal
    // present error to user and return
}

decimal result = textBox19Value + textBox20Value;

textBox21.Text = result;
```